# PHP PDO - bindValue PARAM_BOOL as string

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm freaking out here and can't figure out what's wrong. I'm pretty new to PDO, but everything works in my code except for booleans which are sent as strings.

My code (simplified):

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM pages WHERE clean_url_slo = :clean_url_slo AND published = :published LIMIT 1';

$clean_url_slo = 'home';
$published = true;
```

Then I prepare stuff and execute it like this (simplified):

```
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(':clean_url_slo',$clean_url_slo,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':published',$published,PDO::PARAM_BOOL);
$stmt->execute();
```

And then here is what comes to mysql (from the mysql log - the query mysql received):

```
91 Query    SELECT * FROM pages WHERE 1=1 AND clean_url_slo='domov' AND published='1' ORDER BY id desc LIMIT 1
```

As you can see, published is an integer - so always true, which is not OK. Why is that if I'm declaring it as a boolean?

using:

WAMP SERVER
PHP version: 5.3.9
Mysql: 5.5.20

Many thanks for your help..

Comment: Integer 1 is TRUE even if quoted as a string, integer 0 is FALSE even if quoted as a string.

Comment: Test this with `SELECT '0'=TRUE;` (0), `SELECT '0'=FALSE;` (1)

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I have it set to TINYINT(1) in the DB but I thought that BOOL should be 1 or 0 not '1' and '0'. I've tested it now and it really works.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL does not really have a boolean data type, the BOOLEAN keyword is just an alias of TINYINT(1).
You must work it has an number where 1 = true and 0 = false.
Check [MySQL Data Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/numeric-type-overview.html)

Answer (score 0):

For MySql I would use the datatype as TINYINT(1) And set the data type to PARAM_INT,

I have created a small method:

```
public static function castBoolMysql($value):int
{
    if($value !== 1 && $value !== 0 && !is_bool($value))
    {
        return false;//Incorrect value for bool
    }
    return intval($value);
}

$pdostmt->bindValue(':published', Test::castBoolMysql($published), PDO::PARAM_INT);
```